# Detect click outside an element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have some list items and each contains a small box next to it. Upon clicking on the box, some info is shown. I want to hide the box if a click is outside the box. But i do not know exactly how to do it. There are already some posts similar to this question but all of them are using jQuery but I have to get this done using pure JavaScript

`I tried to do following way:` http://jsfiddle.net/kn8hw4tf/1/

Comment: You have to listen `click` event on entire `document`

Comment: The quickest solution is to add an even listener to `body` and hide the box on click.

Comment: fiddle link is not working

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa: It is not supposed to. The OP has received a warning by the editor that jsfiddle links are not allowed unless accompanied by some code in the question, and he's trying to wriggle around the requirement.

Comment: yeah i cannot place the fiddle link on the post because of the warning: The link is here :http://jsfiddle.net/kn8hw4tf/1/

Comment: @user596502: And instead of pasting some code into your question as the rules say you should, you instead mark a random piece of text as code to avoid the warning? Please do not do so in the future; as a new user you can be forgiven not to know the rules, but this is obviously a case of being told the rules and then going out of your way to disobey them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for clicks anywhere on `document`, and react to them. 
Listen for clicks on the box, and invoke `event.stopPropagation()` so they don't hit the listener on `document`.

```
document.getElementById('test_id').addEventListener('click', function getDetails(evt) {
    var id = this.getAttribute('id');
    alert("Clicked on " + id);
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    alert("Clicked outside");
});
```

Comment: is there any example that i can look forward to or can you please elaborate a bit more. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but your fiddle has so many errors and irrelevant bits that I couldn't understand what you were trying to do exactly. A minimal example demonstrating the concept is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kn8hw4tf/3/).